# Installing ruby 2.0.0-p247 on Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rvm

I am trying to install ruby 2.0 on my ubuntu box and I keep getting the following:

```
SERVER_USER@SERVER_NAME:/var/www/FOLDER_NAME$ rvm get stable && rvm install ruby-2.0.0
ERROR: Unknown ruby interpreter version: '2.0.0'
Installing Ruby from source to: /usr/share/ruby-rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247, this may take     a while depending on your cpu(s)...

ruby-2.0.0-p247 - #fetching
ruby-2.0.0-p247 - #downloading ruby-2.0.0-p247, this may take a while depending on your connection...
curl: (3) <url> malformed
ERROR: There was an error, please check /usr/share/ruby-rvm/log/ruby-2.0.0-p247/*.log.     Next we'll try to fetch via http.
Trying http:// URL instead.
curl: (3) <url> malformed
ERROR: There was an error, please check /usr/share/ruby-rvm/log/ruby-2.0.0-p247/*.log
ERROR: There has been an error while trying to fetch the source.
Halting the installation.
ERROR: There has been an error fetching the ruby interpreter. Halting the installation.
```

The log it mentions also doesn't exist.  Also if it helps at all when I run:

```
rvm requirements
```

I get back

```
ERROR: Unrecognized command line argument: 'requirements' ( see: 'rvm usage' )
```

which i haven't seen before

Comment: What does it say in the log?

Comment: The log doesn't exist, sorry forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 4):

Turns out my rvm was busted because i had used apt-get install ruby-rvm instead of the curl directly from rvm.io, so reinstalling rvm did the trick.