# getting errors while installing ruby 1.9.3

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rvm

i think i have a very silly problem but even i am asking you, because it is making me so irritating and i am new to ruby on rails and  also new to linux ubuntu . while installing the ruby 1.9.3(rvm install 1.9.3) i am getting this  error  that i pasted below .i didn't get any clue from this error . i googled a lot , but can't resolve this so please help me and please elaborate me what this error exactly is?
    i even had been to that path but nothing there in (usr/share/ruby-rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p448)

```
~$ rvm install 1.9.3 

Installing Ruby from source to: /usr/share/ruby-rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...

ruby-1.9.3-p448 - #fetching 
ruby-1.9.3-p448 - #downloading ruby-1.9.3-p448, this may take a while depending on your connection...
curl: (3) <url> malformed
ERROR: There was an error, please check /usr/share/ruby-rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p448/*.log. Next we'll try to fetch via http.
Trying http:// URL instead.
curl: (3) <url> malformed
ERROR: There was an error, please check /usr/share/ruby-rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p448/*.log
ERROR: There has been an error while trying to fetch the source.  
Halting the installation.
ERROR: There has been an error fetching the ruby interpreter. Halting the installation.
```

Comment: Please check this previous answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18513624/1512956

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installed Ruby 1.9.3 with RVM but command line doesn't show ruby -v](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9056008/installed-ruby-1-9-3-with-rvm-but-command-line-doesnt-show-ruby-v)

Comment: Did you check the logs as the error message suggests?

Comment: this is a duplicate because `/usr/share/ruby-rvm` is the ubuntu package which is no more maintained and does not contain update for the new ruby servers.

Comment: did you find any answer I am suffering from same error